# Do select statements start a transaction in auto commit mode?

Tags: sql-server, select, transaction

I knew that update, insert, delete start a transaction in auto commit mode, I would like to ask if select statements make their own transaction also in auto commit mode or there is no need for that ?
and also I would like to know if DDL are auto committed and start their own transaction

Ps: I'm using SQL server if that may make the answer different from one DBMS to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that you can verify by using the [transaction DMVs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/transaction-related-dynamic-management-views-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). For example, if I kick off a long running `SELECT` query then the following query will return at least one row:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_tran_active_transactions t
WHERE name = N'SELECT';
```

Example result set:

[image]

You can use the same method for DDL statements, but it's worth considering what should happen if an `ALTER TABLE` fails before completion. You'd want the table to be restored to the original state, right? Otherwise your database will be corrupt. A transaction is the mechanism that allows for the statement to be rolled back. You will have a transaction with log records any time a statement modifies data in your database in order to avoid database corruption. So yes, DDL statements must use transactions.

Comment: that really helped me knowing that select and DDL start a transaction in auto commit, but what's the purpose of having a select statement in a transaction since it will just retrieve data so if any error happens the data won't be affected and we don't need a log file to know that a failure happened in reading

Comment: The transaction holds the Sch-S and possibly S locks that ensure that the query sees a correct and consistent view of the table's structure and data.

Answer (score 3):

Autocommit mode is the default transaction management mode of the SQL Server Database Engine. Every Transact-SQL statement is committed or rolled back when it completes. If a statement completes successfully, it is committed; if it encounters any error, it is rolled back.

Even selects or DDL statements have their own implicit transaction and so they have autocommit to.
But usually a select has nothing to commit.

Comment: thanks for answering